# Normal html tags like <span>, <p>, <h2> are not rendering in side <ion-list> IONIC

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I’m using IONIC 3.19.1.

```
<ion-content padding>
<ion-list>
  <button ion-item *ngFor="let shift of shifts">
    <h2>{{shift.operatorCode}}</h2>
    <p>{{shift.date}}</p>
    <button>hi</button>
  </button>
</ion-list>
<ion-fab  right bottom>
  <button ion-fab [navPush]="shiftSetup"><ion-icon name="add"></ion-icon></button>
</ion-fab>
</ion-content>
```

in the above code snippet the `<h2>{{shift.operatorCode}}</h2> <p>{{shift.date}}</p>` are note rendering. Pls see the attachment.

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: I made a plunkr with similar code https://plnkr.co/edit/zGenYZz5lzGbWBBTBS9P 
It looks like it working properly. Have you try checking in html dom if the tags are in button ion-items?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are putting the HTML inside a button with the `ion-item` attribute. Change it to just using the `ion-item` element and if you need `click` handling the you can use the binding.

Should look something like this:

```
<ion-content padding>
<ion-list>
  <ion-item *ngFor="let shift of shifts">
    <h2>{{shift.operatorCode}}</h2>
    <p>{{shift.date}}</p>
    <button>hi</button>
  </ion-item>
</ion-list>
<ion-fab  right bottom>
  <button ion-fab [navPush]="shiftSetup"><ion-icon name="add"></ion-icon></button>
</ion-fab>
</ion-content>
```